# The mysql80 service on the local computer started up and then stopped

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when starting the mysql80 service pops up:
"the mysql80 service on the local computer started up and then stopped"

Comment: Please post the mysql error log

Comment: and how to get it?

Comment: by default it is /var/log/mysqld.log

Comment: this file not exist

Answer (score 0):

Log from Workbench:

```
2019-07-14 09:36:30 - Server start done.
2019-07-14 09:36:32 - Checking server status...
2019-07-14 09:36:32 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2019-07-14 09:36:32 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2019-07-14 09:36:32 - Assuming server is not running
2019-07-14 09:36:37 - Checking server status...
2019-07-14 09:36:37 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2019-07-14 09:36:37 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2019-07-14 09:36:37 - Assuming server is not running
```